# sed substitute pattern at the end of line

Tags: bash, sed

I am working with 1.2GB text file. The end pattern needs to be updated from 
'anytext},\n]' to 'anytext}]', where \n is the carriage return in the old pattern.

The following sed commands do not update the pattern

```
sed -i -e 's/},\n]$/}]/' foo.txt
sed -i -e 's/\}\,\n\]$\/}\]/' foo.txt
```

Any idea how to update the pattern? 
I am open to use other bash commands provided it works with the big text file.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to replace an actual carriage return or the literal text `\n`?

Comment: I would like to delete the comma and \n together (",\n" )

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
anytext},
]

$ awk 'NR>1{ if (/^]/) sub("},\n","}",prev); printf "%s",prev } {prev=$0"\n"} END{ printf "%s",prev }' file
anytext}]
```

If that doesn't do what you want then edit your question to provide some representative sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
sed -i "s/\('anytext}\)\(\,[\]n\]'\)/\1]\',/g" test.txt
```

I used grouping here. Grouping is done \(**HERE**\). The first group will preserve the text that does not have to be modified **'anytext}**

The second group just removes the unnecessary text. Then we can refer to the first group by referencing it with a \1 inside of seds replace field and add the text we need **]',**

Then we achieve the desired results:

```
'anytext}]',
```

File:

```
[anthony@localhost ~]$ cat test.txt 

'anytext},\n]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. You need to escape \n. The following works

```
$ echo  'anytext},\n]' | sed -r -e 's/},\\n]$/}]/'
anytext}]
$
```